# Azure appfabric service bus load balancing + session affinity (sticky session)

Tags: azure, appfabric, azureservicebus, wcf-sessions

I was searching through Internet, and what I've found is just it is not possible on Azure external/internal endpoint...
[How does Windows Azure perform load balancing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262307/how-does-windows-azure-perform-load-balancing)

But what I am looking for is, whether session affinity is possible on Service Bus. I even done my own research, with modified `EchoSample`, but with no success. I've tried `ws2007HttpRelayBinding` and `netTcpRelayBinding` and end up with:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote endpoint no
>   longer recognizes this sequence. This is most likely due to an abort
>   on the remote endpoint. The value of srm:Identifier is not a known
>   Sequence identifier. The reliable session was faulted.

So, the question: It is possible to do "service bus load balancing + session affinity"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have sessions persist across Azure to my knowledge. You cannot make any assumptions about which node you will get due to node availability changes. If you need session state - you need to manage it externally from the front end bus (azure database, azure storage, remote db, remote storage etc.). This can be potentially one of the issues with the cloud - you don't get *total* control anymore. You just have to get creative with how you solve it.