# Windows Azure SDK - ASPProviders example

Tags: session, azure

since the new SDK 1.1 is missing the tutorial for "ASPProviders", i am currently asking myself how i would implement a "azure session state provider" ( this is the path in the "old" SDK: C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.0\Samples\AspProviders )

Related threads:
[How does Microsoft Azure handle Session State?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023108/how-does-microsoft-azure-handle-session-state)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/2d1340ed-0ad0-456a-b069-aa6b85672102/

Has anyone an idea or even the old example project and could post some snippets of the config here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old samples are [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazuresamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3526). But here are the caveats:

- They are old and have not been updated in a while
- There are a few bugs (some the result of underlying changes in the Win Azure since then, other simply bugs)
- There are no unit tests, so you will need to either write your own or live with that.

But, it is a starting point if you are interested in using Win Azure storage (tables + blobs).

Answer (score 1):

A version that works is included in the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=413E88F8-5966-4A83-B309-53B7B77EDF78&displaylang=en) (plus a whole lot of other good sample code).

Download the training kit and install it somewhere on your drive, then you should be able to find it at: \Labs\BuildingWebFormAppsWithWindowsAzure\Source\Assets

Don't forget to look at (or copy) the web.config file that configures the providers in: \Labs\BuildingWebFormAppsWithWindowsAzure\Source\Ex1-UsingAzureProviders\End\CS\AzureStore

Its also in the Assets folder for a few of the other examples, but that should work for you.

Comment: These are mostly the same as in the Win Azure SDK additional samples. Some bug fixed, but it mostly the same architecture. I would encourage people to do some heavy testing for your requirements (e.g. load test, perf, etc), before deploying in production.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this a few minutes ago since I'm trying to do the same thing as you:

http://azuresqlsession.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what i am looking for.. i'd rather like to use the storage of azure instead of SQL Azure...