# Azure Development - How to stop a Web Role instance

Tags: azure, development-environment, azure-web-roles

I need to test how my code will handle the failure of a web role instance in a development environment.

How do I terminate one of the instances?  I can't see any option in the UI for this.  Seems like a strange ommission

### Update

The issue is relating to a distributed cache layer (I know that azure offers their own)
I want to be able to test how the system reacts to a missing or additional node etc

Prehaps my real question is

**how up to date is RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Instances**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The need to simulate ungraceful exits in the dev emulator usually is done because you are doing something in your web role that is stateful or long running.  That is generally discouraged, but sometimes is unavoidable.

I suspect the best way to simulate the a failure is to kill processes.  If you open task manager (or better Process Explorer), you will see "WatDebugger" hosting either "WaIISHost" or "WaWorkerHost".  If you kill this process, I think it will simulate a failure.

Honestly, it is easier to test this one in the cloud however.  You can RDP into one of the instances and kill the 'WaAppAgent' process.  That will kill your RoleEntryPoint and fabric controller agent.  That will be a true ungraceful failure.

Comment: Now if you kill this process, it just restarts again after a few seconds!

Answer (score 0):

By failure, do you mean becoming unavailable? It should be seamless because the next request would simply be handled by one of the other instances. As long as there is one instance available Azure will route calls to that instance.

This is the nature of a high-available system, requests are handled by the available instances. This is why you have multiple instances in the first place, to handle requests in the case of failure in one or more instances.

This is why you need to always be watchful of how your application handles state. State needs to be maintained outside of the instance, either in queues or in a database. This ensures that any process can pickup a piece of work and execute against it.

There is another question dealing with Session State that should help: [How does Microsoft Azure handle Session State?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023108/how-does-microsoft-azure-handle-session-state)

Answer (score 0):

By terminate an instance do you mean reducing instance count and see which one gets killed? I like Ryan's view about ungraceful exits, but if it's forced kill by the fabric it'll be a different ball game.